# Automapper forcing me to map every property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have two classes like this:

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

}
```

I want to map `RegistrationViewModel` to `ApplicationUser`, so here's the mapping configuration:

```
public class ViewModelToEntityMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public ViewModelToEntityMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<RegistrationViewModel, ApplicationUser>().ForMember(au => au.UserName, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Email));
    }
}
```

I added AutoMapper to the project in my `Services.cs` file:

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

What I'm expecting is that `RegistrationViewModel.Roles` is ignored during the mapping, since it doesn't exist in `ApplicationUser`, and that all other properties that exist in `IdentityUser` are set to their default values, since I `RegistrationViewModel` doesn't have them.

I'm calling the map like this:

```
var userIdentity = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(model);
```

But this is generating the following exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> AutoMapperConfigurationException:  Unmapped members were found. Review
>   the types and members below. Add a custom mapping expression, ignore,
>   add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type For no
>   matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or
>   map all of the constructor parameters
>   ======================================================================================================================================== RegistrationViewModel -> ApplicationUser (Destination member list)
>   Storefy.ServicesLayer.ViewModels.ViewModels.Authentication.RegistrationViewModel
>   -> Storefy.BusinesLayer.Entities.Users.ApplicationUser (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties: 
>   AccessFailedCount 
>   EmailConfirmed 
>   LockoutEnabled
>   LockoutEnd 
>   PhoneNumberConfirmed 
>   TwoFactorEnabled 
>   Id 
>   NormalizedUserName
>   Email 
>   NormalizedEmail 
>   PasswordHash 
>   SecurityStamp 
>   ConcurrencyStamp
>   PhoneNumber

It seems that AutoMapper is expecting all the properties in the `IdentityUser` to be mapped. This is my first time using AutoMapper, is this the expected behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

AutoMapper has an extension method for ignoring properties. For example you can write like this:

```
CreateMap<RegistrationViewModel, ApplicationUser>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Roles, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue so I wrote an extension method for this.

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> IgnoreAll<TSource, TDest>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> e)
{
    e.ForAllMembers(x => x.Ignore());
    return e;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If anyone comes here in future, it turns out that my mapping configuration was in another project, and AutoMapper wasn't even reading it.

Instead of

```
services.AddAutoMapper()
```

in `Services.cs` I have to add AutoMapper to my project this way:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfileConfiguration());
    });

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

    ...
}
```

Comment: You should simply pass that info to AddAutoMapper. See [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection).